# Merging 2 HashMaps in Java

Tags: java, android, dictionary, hashmap

I have a program that needs to merge two `HashMap`. The hashmaps have a key that is a `String` and a value that is an `Integer`. The special condition of the merge is that if the key is already in the dictionary, the `Integer` needs to be added to the existing value and not replace it. Here is the code I have so far that is throwing a `NullPointerException`.

```
public void addDictionary(HashMap<String, Integer> incomingDictionary) {
        for (String key : incomingDictionary.keySet()) {
            if (totalDictionary.containsKey(key)) {
                Integer newValue = incomingDictionary.get(key) + totalDictionary.get(key);
                totalDictionary.put(key, newValue);
            } else {
                totalDictionary.put(key, incomingDictionary.get(key));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: On what line is the NPE being thrown?

Comment: Have you initialized the `totalDictionary` field?

Comment: totalDictionary is declared but not initialized as private member data earlier in the class wrapping this function. Eclipse shows the exception being thrown at the line with the for loop.

Comment: This probably means that `incomingDictionary` is null or that `incomingDictionary` contains `null` as a key.

Comment: Also, you'll have to initialize `totalDictionary` before you can use it...otherwise you'll get more NPEs.

Comment: The problem is that incomingDictionary is null, then. It shouldn't matter about null keys if either of the maps were to contain one. (Rare case that could cause problems I suppose: one type of map allows null, the other doesn't.)

Comment: Check if the value in one of the hashmap is not null. HashMap allows null

Comment: You might want to look at using Guava's [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) instead of a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: It is the incomingDictionary. I have a class that extracts the hashmap from json and for some reason the Integer is not being extracted correctly. I am working on fixing it and then I'll decide which answer is the most correct (They are all correct). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code cannot guarantee that `incomingDictionary` will be initialized before it reaches this method, you will have to do a null check, no way out

```
public void addDictionary(HashMap<String, Integer> incomingDictionary) {
    if (incomingDictionary == null) {
        return; // or throw runtime exception
    }
    if (totalDictionary == null) {
        return;// or throw runtime exception
    }
    if (totalDictionary.isEmpty()) {
        totalDictionary.putAll(incomingDictionary);
    } else {
        for (Entry<String, Integer> incomingIter : incomingDictionary.entrySet()) {
            String incomingKey = incomingIter.getKey();
            Integer incomingValue = incomingIter.getValue();
            Integer totalValue = totalDictionary.get(incomingKey);
            // If total dictionary contains null for the incoming key it is
            // as good as replacing it with incoming value.
            Integer sum = (totalValue == null ? 
                                            incomingValue : incomingValue == null ? 
                                                    totalValue : totalValue + incomingValue
                          );
            totalDictionary.put(incomingKey, sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Considering HashMap allows null as value another place in your code which is prone to NPE is

```
Integer newValue = incomingDictionary.get(key) + totalDictionary.get(key);
```

if either of these two is null you will get NPE.

Comment: What about if(totalDictionary.isEmpty()) then totalDictionary.putAll(incomingDictionary) else do the for loop?

Comment: if incomingDictionary is null then putAll will throw NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

you have probably one of your dictionnaries not initialized.
Here is one solution:

```
public void addDictionary(HashMap<String, Integer> incomingDictionary) {
    if (incomingDictionary == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("incomingDictionary cannot be null.");
    }
    if (totalDictionary == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("totalDictionary cannot be null.");
        // or another solution:
        // totalDictionary = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        // totalDictionary.putAll(incomingDictionary);
        // return;
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : incomingDictionary.entrySet()) {
        Integer oldValue = totalDictionary.get(entry.getKey());
        if (oldValue != null){
            // here entry.getValue() could be null!
            // Never put a null value in your Map, or add a test here
            Integer newValue = entry.getValue() + oldValue;
            totalDictionary.put(entry.getKey(), newValue);
        } else {
            totalDictionary.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If entry.getValue() returns null, again NPE

Comment: Indeed! but I think it's his responsability to never put `null` as a value in a Map... But I will edit my post according to your comment.

Comment: If the map doesn't contain a value for key in ` getValue(key)`, it can return null;

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `totalDictionary` are correctly initialized, in:

```
Integer newValue = incomingDictionary.get(key) + totalDictionary.get(key);
```

`totalDictionary.get(key)` could not return `null`.
Maybe you need to add something like this before:

```
if(totalDictionary.get(key) == null)
  totalDictionary.put(key, 0);
```